# Why MSE( L2 error) in papers is so small such as 0.05？

Tags: python, mse

[image]

This is the MSE formula.

And here are two python functions to calculate MSE for two **RGB images**. They get the same result. But the result is much more greater than 1.0 such as 43.0, 58.0...

While the MSE(L2 error) in almost all papers are all **much smaller than 1.0 such as 0.05, 0.08...**

And I want to know **how to calculate the MSE results in papers such as 0.05, 0.08.**

```py
def mse_1(img_a,img_b): 
    mse = np.mean( (img_a - img_b) ** 2 )
    return mse
```

```py
def mse_2(img_a,img_b): 
    cnt = img_a.shape[0]*img_a.shape[1]          
    mse_r = (float)(np.sum((img_a[:,:,0] - img_b[:,:,0]) ** 2)) / (float)(cnt)
    mse_g = (float)(np.sum((img_a[:,:,1] - img_b[:,:,1]) ** 2)) / (float)(cnt)
    mse_b = (float)(np.sum((img_a[:,:,2] - img_b[:,:,2]) ** 2)) / (float)(cnt)
    mse = (mse_r+mse_g+mse_b)/3.0
    return mse
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you normalized the image data before calcuating MSE? That could be why you are not getting as low MSE as other papers.

Comment: No, I didn't normalize the image data, every pixel is between 0 and 255. I'll try to normalize image, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Note: You can try few ranges such as [0,1] and [0,1] for normalization.
Also if the normalization solves your issue please accept this as the answer so other users wont lose time coming up with other possible answers such as explaining image scaling. If It doest work let me know and I will delete/edit this answer and help you furter.

Comment: The normalization sovles my problem.

Comment: I have another question, now that we need to normalize image before calculating MSE. **Do we also need to normalize image before calculating SSIM and PSNR?** They are all used to calculate the similarity between two images. And this is the sample code:`from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim` `from skimage.metrics import peak_signal_noise_ratio as psnr` `ssim_result = ssim(img_a_norm,img_b_norm,multichannel=True)` `psnr_result = psnr(img_a_norm,img_b_norm)`